# Adding string array (string[]) to List<string> c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

When the string[], _lineParts is added to the List, all I see in the List is "System.String[]"
 What needs to be done to see the actually string[] values in the list.

```
while (_aLine != null) 
{ 
    //split the line read into parts delimited by commas 
    _lineParts = _aLine.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\u000A', ',', '.', ';', ':', '-', '_', '/' }, 
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
    //keep things going by reading the next  line 
    _aLine = sr.ReadLine(); 
    //words = _lineParts; 
    if (_lineParts != null) 
    { 
        //_words.Add(_lineParts.ToString()); 
        wrd.Add(_lineParts.ToString()); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You're not adding `_lineParts` to the list, you're adding `_lineParts.ToString()` to the list.  The default behavior of `ToString()` for reference types is to output the type name, which in this case is `System.String[]`.  Are you trying to add each individual element from the array to the list?  Or are you trying to add the entire array as a single element to the list?

Comment: Each individual element from array to list.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use [List.AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange) instead of    `List.Add`

Answer (score 26):

Use [List.AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/z883w3dc(v%3dvs.95)) instead of [List.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/3wcytfd1(v%3dvs.95))

*Change*

```
 wrd.Add(_lineParts.ToString());
```

*To*

```
wrd.AddRange(_lineParts);
```

Comment: nice - suddenly i remember why i love javascript :-P

Answer (score 5):

You can use `List.AddRange()` where you are using `List.Add()`