# How to append an array to a List using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following piece of code:

```
private List<IComponent> _components;

protected void UsePageComponents(params IComponent[] components) => _components = components.ToList();
```

I receive an array with `params` and I would like to append this array to the List (`_components`)`? How do I accomplish this using LINQ?

Comment: `_components.AddRange(components);`?

Comment: [List<T>.AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/z883w3dc(v%3dvs.95))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding string array (string\[\]) to List<string> c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882778/adding-string-array-string-to-liststring-c-sharp) The answer is valid fro any type of objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conversion of System.Array to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603170/conversion-of-system-array-to-list)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need LINQ; `List<T>.AddRange` will do:

```
protected void UsePageComponents(params IComponent[] components)
{
    _components.AddRange(components);
}
```

It accepts `IEnumerable<T>` which `T[]` implements.